# A.N.T. Landscape Interface

Tags: interface

when I first open a landscape mesh, I can see the mesh interface (large yellow box), and I can minimize it (small yellow box), but when I click off the mesh, the interface disappears and I cannot find the menu anywhere! Any ideas how I can re-open the Landscape interface?! Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: F9 will bring it back at the position of the mouse cursor, but that's only as long as you haven't made __any__ other changes in the interim.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for that. Is there any way to bring it back if I have made other changes or is it lost forever?

Comment: See the answer from @Foxtrot. Note that this doesn't just apply to the landscape interface. It applies to **any** object after you've created it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey once you clicked anywhere you can bring back last operation menu by pressing F9
but if you do another operation after it (like scale,location,rotate) it will lost.

Comment: So after I do something else, I can never edit that landscape?!

Comment: You need to save the settings as operator presents to use that settings